# Do I need a Google Apps Account for GCE?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are working on testing email on-premise and may be considering moving away from Google Apps for Email. Our current projects within GCE are tied to our current Google Apps Email accounts. Do we have to use Google Apps Email in order to use GCE? If not, does anyone know how login to the GCE web console would work since it is currently tied to our Google Apps Email accounts?

I can't seem to find a proper way to shift the project to a non-google authentication method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need a Google account to use Google Cloud Platform services. However, it doesn't need to be a Google Apps account, you can use a free Gmail account as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a google "apps" account for everything since you will have to pay for your GCE and payment comes from a profile that is associated with that account.

If you move your email, assuming your domain is using Google's services now, I think you Google account will still use that domain's email login for the Google account even if you change your MX records to use a different email host.

Or maybe I don't understand your question ...

Comment: StackitUp, you definitely understood my question. Thanks for the response. If that is the case, that seems a bit harsh that you can't use GCE unless if you have Google Services/App. It's almost an all or nothing type of deal. You pretty much have to pay for two different products just because you want one. For example, I have to pay for a Google Apps account in order to use VMs within GCE. Sigh